# Is it possible to run VACUUM command inside Celery Task?

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions, celery, vacuum

I have celery periodic task that need to run postgres VACUUM query after each run, otherwise this task eats a lot of HDD space.

I tried to run VACUUM inside task at the end, but got error:

```
DatabaseError: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block
```

I tried to apply `@transaction.commit_manually` decorator and do `transaction.commit()` before calling VACUUM, but got this error:

```
TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

Is there way to do VACUUM inside celery task? Or somehow disable for task transaction logic?

Comment: If it eats up disk space, it probably is because it needs it (disk page splits for mvcc, etc.)... Is it still eating extra space when you run similar transactions multiple times?

Comment: yes, without VACUUM. This problem about inserting new rows to table with huge text field. That's what my task do.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not usually have to vacuum unless you just did a huge bulk delete.  Just make sure autovacuum is running, and is enabled.  It will do this in the background and you won't have to worry about it.

Secondly you could fire off a system command to run the vacuumdb command line tool.  This would do it in a separate session.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to consider:

1. Unfortunately, `VACUUM` cannot be executed inside a Transaction.
2. Django default behavior is to run queries in AUTOCOMMIT mode.
3. You can adjust the "Autovacuum daemon", if **Dead tuples** are frequent on your database tables.

Running `VACUUM ANALYZE` (clean and report statistics back to the db planner), manually, would uncommon.

If you are curious about possible Dead Tuples, you can run just `ANALYZE`, and first observe if indeed, the database tables are infested with Dead Tuples:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -c "ANALYZE VERBOSE" 2>&1 | grep -E --color "[1-9][1-9]? dead rows"
```

For further reference:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-vacuum.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-autovacuum.html